# Codeigniter 2 and Doctrine 22

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-2

Ok so I followed this tutorial here: 
http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/

Every thing has gone well, except for the last step and most import of actually trying to use the Entity in my controller. I keep getting this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Entities\Categories' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/controllers/home.php on line 43

Any ideas on what is causing this issue? I have tried a few things suggested on SO, but none seem to be working. A little frustrating, this tutorial is a bit old. Anyway see anything that is an issue? Not very familiar with doctrine.

Comment: what is your namespace? did u "import" the class like? "use Entities\Categories;

Comment: In the tutorial it sets up the categories so you don't need to import the categories. I also tried that as well anyway. I actually get this when I try that. PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Entities\Categories' not found So something is not right in loading these classes